# Como aplicar filtro the_content na função get_the_content WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, controller

Estou desenvolvendo um tema para WordPress, por hobby e para estudar um pouco de PHP, JavaScript etc. e estou enfrentando um pequeno problema.

Estou trabalhando com o conceito de controlador onde toda lógica será processada e depois enviada para uma view. Para deixar mais claro como está estruturado meu tema vou passar a minha estrutura de diretórios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `controller-single.php` irá controlar os dados que serão renderizados no `single.php` nele eu defino a classe `Controller_Single` que vai gerenciar o conteúdo da página/posts e depois eu chamo as partes necessárias para e exibição do conteúdo:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../security.php';

class Controller_Single {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'get_single_content', array( $this, 'get_single_content' ) );
    }

    public function get_single_content() {
        $single_content = new StdClass();
        $single_content->title = get_the_title(); // Título do Post
        $single_content->author = get_the_author(); // Autor do Post
        $single_content->date = get_the_date(); // Data de publicação
        $single_content->content = get_the_content(); // Conteúdo do Post
        return $single_content;
    }
}

new Controller_Single();
```

E no meu single.php eu realizo a chamada do conteúdo:

```
<?php
get_header();
the_post();
$single_post = apply_filters( 'get_single_content', false );
?>

<header class="glory-header">
    <div class="glory-header-title">
        <h2><?php echo $single_post->title ?></h2>
        <p>Publicado por: <span><?php echo $single_post->author ?></span> em <?php echo $single_post->date ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="glory-header-overlay"></div>
</header>

<div class="glory-page-body">
    <?php echo $single_post->content ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

O problema é que, como eu estou usando `get_the_content();` no controller.php ao invés de `the_content();` o WordPress não realiza o *auto embeds* o que é um problema pra mim já que eu vou trabalhar com shortcodes, galerias etc.

No entanto, se eu utilizar o `the_content();` o conteúdo do post aparece logo após a abertura da tag `<body>` e, por consequência, acima de todos os elementos da página (header, nav etc.).

Já li sobre a possibilidade de contornar isso, no entanto, não consegui encontrar uma solução funcional para o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu controller você pode aplicar o filtro `the_content` logo que busca os conteúdos, por exemplo:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../security.php';

class Controller_Single {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'get_single_content', array( $this, 'get_single_content' ) );
    }

    public function get_single_content() {
        $single_content = new StdClass();
        $single_content->title = get_the_title(); // Título do Post
        $single_content->author = get_the_author(); // Autor do Post
        $single_content->date = get_the_date(); // Data de publicação
        $single_content->content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ); // Conteúdo do Post
        return $single_content;
    }
}

new Controller_Single();
```